# Set a value to return when something is selected in HTML select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

I have a list to be selected in html select element. Those are: Indian Rupee (INR), US Dollar (USD), etc. When I select one option, and access `document.getElementById("someId").value` in JavaScript, I get the whole string: Indian Rupee (INR). Instead, I want only "INR" for further code.

I know that I can implement regex ad extract INR from the string, but I am eager to know is there any way to set a return value which can be accessed by code when something in HTML select drop down is selected.

Eg: when I select Indian Rupee (INR), is there any way that I can directly get "INR"? Like setting some property for that value beforehand or something else?

Comment: You mean like `<option value="INR">Indian Rupee (INR)</option>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you should change your approach. Not assign to whole text as option value. It should be text.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("someId").value);
```

```html
<select id="someId">
  <option value="INR">Indian Rupee (INR)</option>
</select>
```

If you insist about to extract the `INR` using `regex`, try the following code;

```js
var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
var matches = regExp.exec(document.getElementById("someId").value);
console.log(matches[1]);
```

```html
<select id="someId">
  <option value="Indian Rupee (INR)">Indian Rupee (INR)</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

In case it is like I understood and you don't need the full name may I suggest that you set the value to INR or USD only as follows:

```
<select>
   <option value="INR">Indian Rupee (INR)</option>
   <option value="USD"> US Dollar (USD)</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your select option may have`value = "USD"`and html text "US Dollar (USD)". They are 2 diferent things.

```
<option value="USD">US Dollar (USD)</option>
```